# get number only in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string likes

```
AA-12,AB-1,AC-11,AD-8,AE-30
```

I want to get number only from this string likes

```
12,1,11,8,30
```

How can I get this using JavaScript ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex, eg

```
var numbers = yourString.match(/\d+/g);
```

`numbers` will then be an array of the numeric strings in your string, eg

```
["12", "1", "11", "8", "30"]
```

Comment: Looks like you forget about join with comma separator

Comment: @FSou1 I forgot nothing. An array is much easier to work with and can be transformed into a comma delimited string easily enough using `numbers.join(',')`

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want a string as the result

```
'AA-12,AB-1,AC-11,AD-8,AE-30'.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = "AA-12,AB-1,AC-11,AD-8,AE-30";
alert(t.match(/\d+/g).join(','));
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tZQ9w/2/

Answer (score 1):

if this is exactly what your input looks like, I'd split the string and make an array with just the numbers:

```
var str = "AA-12,AB-1,AC-11,AD-8,AE-30";
var nums = str.split(',').map(function (el) {
    return parseInt(el.split('-')[1], 10);
});
```

The split splits the string by a delimiter, in this case a comma. The returned value is an array, which we'll map into the array we want. Inside, we'll split on the hyphen, then make sure it's a number.

Output:

```
nums === [12,1,11,8,30];
```

I have done absolutely no sanity checks, so you might want to check it against a regex:

```
/^(\w+-\d+,)\w+-\d+$/.test(str) === true
```

You can follow this same pattern in any similar parsing problem.