# How can I take out numeric characters from a string and put them in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this string:

```
[{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"1"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}]
```

How can I take out the `"2", "1", "2"` and put them in an array using JavaScript?

Comment: There are lots of ways, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get number only in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668462/get-number-only-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few helpful resources: https://regexr.com/ https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex

```js
console.log(
'[{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"1"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}]'
.match(/\d+/g)
);
```

(This assumes each number is a single digit)

For the sake of pointing out bad code.. I wrote the following as a "fun" update to show a @Anupam's answer below. It abuses a few things... and I much prefer the regex solution.

```js
console.log(
'[{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"1"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}]'
.split('[{"COUNT(post_id)":"')
.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x); })
.filter(isFinite)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

not a clean way but try on the lines

```js
    var str = '[{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"1"}][{"COUNT(post_id)":"2"}]';
    var res = str.split('[{"COUNT(post_id)":"');
    var res1 = res.toString();
    var res3 = res1.split('"}]');
    var res4 = res3.toString().split(',,');
    document.write(res4);
```